# Is atlas-run the only way to see how the changes are reflected?

Tags: bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am new to Atlassian development so bear with me. Should we build the project every time using `atlas-run` command to see how the code is reflected when it is run? It takes a long time for the project to build itself eachtime. Is there a way to hotfix the code? Or some other alternative solution that makes this process easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `atlas-debug` to start an instance at Tomcat/Stash, and then on a separate console run `atlas-cli`, and from there `pi` (plugin-install) which will redeploy just your plugin without a restart.

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/atlas-cli

You might want to read some of the docs on that site. Also, there's more of a speciic Atlassian community on their SO-like Answers site here (which is handy for searching for questions too):

https://answers.atlassian.com/